# Issue with promises in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, callback, promise

I'm confronted to a situation which drives me a bit mad.

So The situation is as below :

```js
module.exports = {
  
  generation: function (req, res) {

    // Let's firstly fetch all the products from the productTmp Table
    function fetchProductsTmp (){
      ProductsTmp.find().then(function (products) {
        return Promise.all(products.map (function (row){
           Service.importProcess(row);
        }));
      });
    }
    fetchProductsTmp();
  }
```

Here I simply call my model ProductsTmp to fetch my datas and iterate through my rows calling importProcess.

importProcess :

```js
importProcess: function (product) {

    async.series([
      function (callback) {
        return SousFamille.findOne({name: product.sous_famille}).then(function (sf) {
          console.log('1');
          if (!sf) {
            return SousFamille.create({name: product.sous_famille}).then(function (_sf)             {
              console.log('2');
              callback(null, _sf.sf_id);
            });
          } else {
              callback(null, sf.sf_id);
          }
        });
      },
      function (callback){
        console.log('3');
      },
    ], function(err, results){
      if(err) return res.send({message: "Error"});

    });
      
}
```

So I got with my console log :
1
1
1
2
3
2
3
2
3

What I want to Obtain is 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 So that each function wait for the promise to finish before calling the next one.

Comment: You forgot to return the actual promises for Promise.all.
`return Promise.all(products.map (function (row){
     return Service.importProcess(row);
 }));`

Comment: You really shouldn't use `async.series` when you can just use promises.

Comment: @noppa Thanks for your answer but it doesn't resolve the situation

Comment: @Bergi Why is it not recommended ?

Comment: @musecz: Because promises are so much better and simpler than `async`. In your case, not returning a promise from `importProcess` is even the reason why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, can't help the urge to do it in ES6, basically things can be reduced to single line, like Bergi said, async is redundant( using Bluebird Promise Library):

```
importProcess: product => 
                  SousFamille.findOne({name: product.sous_famille})
                    .then(sf =>  sf? sf.sf_id : SousFamille.create({name: product.sous_famille}).then(_sf => _sf.sf_id))

// the other module
module.exports = {

  generation: (req, res) => ProductsTmp.find()
                              .then(products => Promise.mapSeries(products, Service.importProcess.bind(Service)) )
                              .then(ids => res.send({ids}))
                              .catch(error => res.send({message: 'Error'}))
  }
```

also like noppa said, your problem is the missing `return` in `Service.importProcess(row)`, same code in ES5:

```
module.exports = {

  generation: function (req, res) {

      ProductsTmp.find()
        .then(function (products) {
          return Promise.mapSeries(products, Service.importProcess.bind(Service)) );
      }).then(function(ids){
        res.send({ids: ids});
      }).catch(function(error){
        res.send({message: 'Error'});
      })
}


importProcess: function (product) {

    return SousFamille.findOne({name: product.sous_famille})
      .then(function (sf) {
          if (sf) return sf.sf_id;
          return SousFamille.create({name: product.sous_famille})
                    .then(function (_sf){ return _sf.sf_id});
    });      
}
```

Comment: The `importProcess` function in this one is obviously much nicer, but this doesn't fix the issue OP has, which is about concurrent calls to Service.importProcess. See my answer for a fix on that.

Comment: I do Love the ES6 way to write it ! But how can I call my actions in series, for e.g. : SousFamille.findOne({name: product.sous_famille}).then.... Famille.findOne({}).... Is there a better way than making a long list of then ?

Comment: @musecz are you using bluebird promises, if yes, you can try, `Promise.mapSeries(products, Service.importProcess.bind(Service))` instead of `Promise.all...`

Comment: @mido No i don't, do you recommend using it ?

Comment: @musecz yes, very useful library, especially methods like promisify and promisifyAll which converts async calls into promises, got tons of other useful methods too... check out their [doc](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html)

Comment: @mido Thank you for that. a last question, using blueBird in my service.importProcess, what is the syntax to serialise my actions, for instance, function sousFamille { sousFamile.findOne({})...} then once it's done call function Famille { ...} then call ... and finally return to the generation function

Comment: @musecz updated answer, you need to update `generation` method, you could leave the `importProcess` as it is...

Comment: @mido Thanks it works like a charm. Just why do you use Promise.bind() in  mapseries ?

Comment: @musecz if you are not using any `Service` object dependent operation in `importProcess`, then you can leave out the bind...

Answer (score 1):

In the `generation` function of the first section, replace

```
return Promise.all(products.map (function (row){
    Service.importProcess(row);
}));
```

with

```
var results = [],
    pushResult = id => results.push(id);
return products.reduce(function(prev, row){//Go through all the products
    //Take the previous promise, and schedule next call to Service.importProcess to be
    //made after the previous promise has been resolved
    return prev.then(function(){
        return Service.importProcess(row).then(pushResult);
    });
}, Promise.resolve())
.then(() => results);
```

You also need to return a promise from `importProcess` for this to work. Just ditch the whole `async.series` thingy and do something like

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     ...
     resolve(sf.sf_id); //instead of the callback(null, sf.sf_id)
     ...
});
```

**Update:** This forces the calls to Service.importProcess to be sequential instead of concurrent, which does affect the overall performance of calls to `generation`. But I guess you have more solid reasons to do so than sequential console.logs.

Comment: you missed one thing, he would probably need all the ids, in your current solution, they might get lost except the last one...

Comment: Yeah I will have to do lots of actions in series and save the ids to use later. This is why I firstly use async for this problem

Comment: @mido you're right. I've updated the answer to cover that